# Windows 10 - monitor doesn't turn back on

Tags: windows, windows-10, graphics-card, display, intel-graphics

I'm running Windows 10. My graphics adapter is an integrated Intel HD Graphics 630 chip. My monitor is an Acer XR342CK. The monitor is connected via DisplayPort.

I frequently experience the following:

- I walk away from my desk for a few minutes (doesn't matter if I lock the computer or not)
- The computer does *not* go to sleep. I have it set to never sleep, and I'll frequently have long-running processes going, so I know it's not sleeping.
- After a few minutes, the monitor turns off to save power.
- When I come back, I move the mouse or tap the keyboard to wake the monitor back up.
- The monitor doesn't wake back up, even though the computer is definitely still running.
- I have to turn the monitor off and then back on to get a signal.
- All my windows have been resized to 800x600, and I have to go resize them all.

I have tried the following to resolve it:

- Updating the graphics adapter drivers (most recent are already installed).
- Updating the monitor drivers (most recent are already installed).
- Checking the physical connection of the DisplayPort cable (it's fine).
- Selecting a different input with the monitor, then going back to DisplayPort (doesn't work, it'll just tell me there's no signal on DisplayPort and I have to turn the monitor off and back on to get it to work).
- Using other connection types (not possible, can't drive this monitor at the proper resolution without DisplayPort, unless I'm mistaken).

As a workaround, I decided to set my monitor to only turn off after 2 hours. However, I'm now running into *another* issue - despite being clearly set to turn off after 2 hours, it'll frequently turn off when I've been away from my desk for only a few minutes.

Does anybody have suggestions for resolving this? I've done a lot of Googling about it, but almost everything I can find is related to monitors not turning back on when the PC comes out of sleep, which isn't specifically my issue, and the proposed solutions are mostly what I've already tried anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same exact problem once. Its probably a hardware issue with the monitor. I had to changed the electrolytic capacitor of the monitor, after which it was fine again for years. My workaround was turning the monitor off and on a few times then off, and then wait a few minutes before turning it back on again. Luckily I had a friendly electrition solder the electrolytic capacitor in for me, so I cannot explain how to do it, but you can check if you can see defect electrolytic capacitor after taking off the back of your monitor.

Comment: Elkos being German for capacitors?

Comment: ah, yes sorry. electrolytic capacitor

Comment: Missed one elkos.

Answer (score 0):

Windows allows you to determine how long you wish the PC to wait before blanking or turning off the monitor. You may find that a useful solution to this issue.

Right-click on the Windows Start icon, then choose Power Options.

[image: Power Options settings]

The first option at right is Screen; change that to **Never**, then close the window.

Comment: I've tried changing it to 2 hours, and it still turns off after 5 minutes, as mentioned before. I might have to try Never just for kicks and giggles. Sorry, climate. I tried.